# Power BI continuous x-axis using days and hours

Tags: powerbi, ssas

I have a Power BI report connected to a SSAS tabular model. We have a date/day dimension table (day is the lowest grain) and a time dimension table (second is the lowest grain). We are trying to build a line graph with date and time on the x-axis hierarchically.

When we use just Date from the date table, we can get a continuous axis or when we use just Hour from the time table we get a continuous axis. However, when we bring in Date and Hour to create our hierarchical x-axis, our date shows up continuous, but when "Expand all down one level in the hierarchy" to show date and time, the axis switches to categorical.

The fields we are using for the axis are formatted as Date/Time, which is why they seem to work individually. How do we need to set up our data so the axis can remain continuous as we expand down the hierarchy?